# Parsing HTML with Php

Tags: php, html, xhtml

I cant get the data between the tags into the arrays:

```
// Load the HTML string from file and create a SimpleXMLElement
$html_string = file_get_contents("data/csr.html"); /*the string really is in $html_string*/
$root = new SimpleXMLElement($html_string);
```

Problem starts here when I try to get that the value between the tags: div, h2 and span into an array

```
// Fetch all div, h2 and span values
$divArray = $hdlsArray = $dtlsArray = array();
    foreach ($root->div as $div) {
    $divArray[] = $div;
    echo "".$div."<br />";
}
foreach ($root->h2 as $h2) {
    $hdlsArray[] = $h2;
    echo "".$h2."<br />";
}
foreach ($root->span as $span) {
    $dtlsArray[] = $span;
    echo "".$span."<br />";
}
```

The result of this is a blank page instead of printing the actual tag data

Answer (score 2):

As an alternate to SimpleXMLElement, I suggest [Simple HTML DOM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/) ([online manual](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)). I've used it before and very much satisfied with the results. It allows you to use jQuery like selectors so fetching all div, h2 and span values is fairly simple.

Comment: I didn't really wanted to go third party but I guess right now it seems the best alternative. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://drewish.com/content/2007/08/using_simplexml_with_html) says (about SimpleXML) "the only problem with it is that it'll only load valid XML" but may provide a workaround for HTML.

The 'Related Questions' on StackOverflow include [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553676/accessing-html-inside-xml-using-simplexml-in-php), but it describes HTML *inside* valid XML tags.

Comment: This looks like the old code I had before trying simplexml. And furthermore that returns errors(new DOMDocument). The errors I know are because some conflict with zend extensions. This is the reason why I am using simplexml instead.

Just need to get the inner data between the tags into an array.

Comment: Unfortunately for me, that last link had very little relevance to what I was trying to accomplish here but I really like your spirit.